# Long Selector width in grid

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm trying to make an wp8 app but im struggling with the longlistselector.

My list is in a grid and I would like to see that the list has the same width as the grid, but I don't want to use the hardcoded widths.

here is my code:

```
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                x:Name="GetSubject" 
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                                IsGroupingEnabled="False" 
                                SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged_1" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                        
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
```

But when i add items, the width doesn't change. But when i give the longlistselector a set width, the items are there.

The list with the items is an observablecollection

```
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var files = await folder.GetItemsAsync();
        ObservableCollection<ListSubject> subs = new ObservableCollection<ListSubject>();

        subs.Add(new ListSubject("Foo"));
        subs.Add(new ListSubject("Bar"));



        foreach (var f in files)
        {

            if (f.IsOfType(StorageItemTypes.File) && f.Name.EndsWith(".subj"))
            {
                subs.Add(new ListSubject(f.Name.Remove(f.Name.Length - 5)));
            }

        }

        this.GetSubject.ItemsSource = subs;
```

So how do get the longselectorlist to be the width of the grid it is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have set the **HorizontalAlignment** property of you **LongListSelector** to left that's why it is happening . so you have set it **Stretch** like this..

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, hadn't seen that option :P